# Поиск по http/https в строке по регулярному выражению и замена на ссылку

Tags: php

Уважаемые знатоки, помогите разобраться.
Мне нужно в тексте сообщения найти текст который начинается на **http/https://site.ru...** и заменить его на нормальную ссылку. т.е. < a href="сюда записать http/https://site.ru..." >сюда site.ru< /a >
Для чего методом гугла и "должно работать" написал регулярку
`/^(http[s]*:\/\/)([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)\/*([a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9\.\_\-\/\&\=\?\%]*)$/`
сайт regex101.com говорит что вроде как работает, хотя выглядит ужасно)))
если я правильно понимаю, то preg_replace или preg_replace_callback поможет.
осталась реализация, но как это правильно сделать не понятно...

Comment: [`~https?://(\S+)~`](https://regex101.com/r/VTatr5/2)

Comment: а как быть если ссылка например: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.meta.php а текст ссылки нужен толь php.net

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/VTatr5/3   v3 поразительно, но работает)))

Comment: `~https?://([^/]+)~`

Answer (score 1):

попробуй банально так

```
http\/(.+?)\.\.\.
```

ну и второй вариант )

```
http.?:\/\/(.+?)\s
```

Comment: хотя вопрос не очень ясен

Comment: имеется текст: здесь написан какой то текст ... http/https://site.ru... все что начинает на http/https://site.ru... нужно записать в href="", а между тегами <a> </a> краткое содержание  site.ru

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

```
$text = "
    Текст текст текст любой - https://yandex.ru Вот так!
";
preg_match_all('~http[s]?://(\S+)~',$text,$res);

$newSite = '<a href="'.$res[0][0].'"/>'.$res[1][0].'</a>';

$text = preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([\w]*?)((ht|f)tp(s)?:\/\/[\w]+[^ \,\"\n\r\t<]*[^ \.])/is", $newSite, $text);

print_r($text);
```